# foreach variable not defined in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel and want to populate my view using foreach .
This is view:

```
<thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sr. No.</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>

                                    <th>Mobile No</th>
                                    <th>Email ID</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php  foreach($result as $res){?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td><?php echo $res->vendor_name;?></td>

                                    <td><?php echo $res->mobile;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $res->email;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $res->city;?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".Upcoming" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               <?php  }?>
```

Controller:

```
class VendorController extends Controller
{
  public function getVendorList(){
      $vendors=DB::table('vendor_master')->get();
      $data['result']=$vendors;
       $data['header'] = View::make('header')->render();
        $data['footer'] = View::make('footer')->render();
        return view('vendor_details', $data);
  }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::controller('vendor','VendorController');
```

I am trying from quite sometime but not getting through.A liitle help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong syntax try this [correct syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops)

Comment: your trying to apply codigniter data send format in laravel

Comment: cant we do like what we do incodeigniter

Comment: no .laravel bit differ . data should be passed like i mentioned below .

Comment: thanks @JYoThI.I will try over this using foreach syntax in laravel

Comment: @JYoThI it is still showing result as undefined variable when taken in foreach ?what hast to be done  now??

Comment: first  print the variable in view <?php  if(isset($result)) {  print_r($result); exit;  } else { echo "result  variable not passing to view ";} ?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148668/discussion-between-jyothi-and-pranil-pagare).

Answer (score 1):

Data should be passed like this using `compact()` based on version it will little bit change read documentation here [laravel documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)

```
class VendorController extends Controller
{
  public function getVendorList(){
      $vendors=DB::table('vendor_master')->get();
      $result=$vendors;
       $header = View::make('header')->render();
        $footer = View::make('footer')->render();
        return view('vendor_details',compact( 'result','header','footer'));
  }
}
```

**Note :** your trying to apply `codigniter` data send format in `laravel`